# ADT Eclipse execute code during Debug like xCode

Tags: android, xcode, eclipse, debugging, adt

Can you execute code during debug in ADT Eclipse like "po" in xCode console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In eclipse go to menu Window -> Show View -> Other. Then search for Display view(should be in Debug folder). Double click on it to show Display view. While in debug you can execute comand inside Display view by selecting it and pressing "Display result of selected Text" button in the right top corner of the Display view.